# How to add/set Query Parameters in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

So I've been adding query parameters in my URL like

```
[URL]/?param1=value1&param2=value2
```

But how do I do it like I would in HTTP headers which could be set like this.

```
private HttpHeaders generateCredetialsHeader() {
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.add("ClientId", clientId);
    headers.add("ClientSecret",clientSecret);
    return headers;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`UriComponentsBuilder`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/util/UriComponentsBuilder.html):

```
String urlTemplate = "https://example.com/hotels/42?param1={p1}&param2={p2}";

String url = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl(urlTemplate)
        .buildAndExpand("value1", "value2")
        .toUriString();

// Or:
String url = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl(urlTemplate)
        .buildAndExpand(Map.of("p1", "value1",
                               "p2", "value2"))
        .toUriString();
```

Alternatively, don't do it as a template, but add query parameters separately:

```
String url = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl("https://example.com/hotels/42")
        .queryParam("param1", "value1")
        .queryParam("param2", "value3")
        .toUriString();
```

Comment: I edited your answer to reflect what worked for me, hopefully that would get accepted so that I could then mark this an answer then. Thanks btw.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JSON like this:

> `https://www.google/com/path?jsonStr={"key":"value","key1":"value1"}`

Answer (score 0):

For Passing Query Param Just use UriComponentsBuilder like this-

```
    UriComponentsBuilder builder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl(url).queryParam("value1", "abcvalue");
```